# Strong convergence in supremum norm of countably infinite set implies strong convergence in sum of absolute values?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

If $|p_n(i) - p(i)| \rightarrow 0$ almost surely and $\sup_{1\leq i<\infty} |p_n(i) - p(i)| \rightarrow 0 $ almost surely, does that imply strong convergence in this sense: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|p_n(i) - p(i)| \rightarrow 0$ almost surely?

Here $p_n$ and p are pmfs.

Answer (score 1):

no, even here, where for each $n$ :  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |p_n(i)| = 1$. you need stronger assumptions :

see what [Terence Tao calls escape to "width infinity"](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/),

> Example 2. (Escape to **width infinity**) Let $p_n := \frac{1}{n} 1_{\{1 \ldots n\}}$ Then ${p_n}$ converges to zero uniformly (and thus, pointwise, in $l^\infty$ norm, ..) **but not in $l^1$ norm**.